# how to send a zip file back end to front end in nodejs using express server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, zip

I am building an application where it is required to save data into separate and compress these files into a zip file. these files are at the back end and i could not send this back end created zip file to front end which is react in this case

### express js code

```
app.post("/download",function(request,response,next){
    let sheets=request.body["sheets"];
    let charts=request.body["charts"];
    let compressedSheets=LZString.compress(JSON.stringify(sheets));

    fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/public/dataModel.txt', compressedSheets, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Replaced!');

      },()=>{
        fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/public/Report.json',charts,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        },()=>{
            var archiver = require('archiver');
            var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/public/example.zip');
            var archive = archiver('zip', {
                gzip: true,
                zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
            });

            archive.on('error', function(err) {
            throw err;
            });
            archive.pipe(output);
            archive.file(__dirname+'/public/dataModel.txt', {name: 'dataModel.txt'});
            archive.file(__dirname+'/public/Report.json', {name: 'Report.json'});


            archive.finalize().then(()=>{
                response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=example.zip');
                response.download(__dirname+'/public/example.zip');
            });

        })
      });
```

### react code

```
handleSaveAs=function(){


    let data=new FormData();
    data.append('sheets',JSON.stringify(this.state.sheets));
    data.append('charts',JSON.stringify(this.state.charts));


    axios
    .post("http://localhost:4001/download",data)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      const element = document.createElement("a");
      const file = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/zip'});
      element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      element.download = "untitled.zip";
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
    })
```

provided all the imports are handled properly and the zip file is created properly at the back end. problem is only with sending that to front end

any help would be appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built `fs` of Node.js to stream the data to the front-end.

```js
//Filestream middleware that takes in the file path as the parameter

const streamW = (pathToZip) => {
 return (req, res, next) => {

//Create a readable stream
const readableStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToZip, 'the_encoding_here');

//Pipe it into the HTTP response
readableStream.pipe(res)

  next();

}};

//The route that you want to hit using the front-end to get the file
//Call the middleware and pass in the path to the zip
router.get('/downloadRoute', streamW('path_to_zip'), (req, res) => {

     //Send the data to the front end by calling res
     res

// });
```

Answer (score 0):

This you do in node js download route

```
     archive.finalize().then(()=>{
  let filetext = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/public/example.zip');

  return res.end(new Buffer(filetext ).toString('base64'));
});
```

On frontend do something like this

handleSaveAs=function(){

```
let data=new FormData();
data.append('sheets',JSON.stringify(this.state.sheets));
data.append('charts',JSON.stringify(this.state.charts));


axios
.post("http://localhost:4001/download",data)
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
  let elem = window.document.createElement('a');
    elem.href = "data:application/zip;base64,"+res;
    elem.download = "my.zip";        
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.click();        
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
})
```